# Driver Development DbgengRemoteCommand is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, wdk

I have 2 machines with win 10 Enterprise(clean install) and visual studio 2015 with WDK 10. 
I have made one of the machine the host and one the target. 
By following the msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn745909(v=vs.85).aspx).

I followed the instructions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439659(v=vs.85).aspx) and also tried the next example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx)

Both examples gave me the same error "DbgengRemoteCommand" is missing.

I can see the target computer from Drive Install  >  Deployment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem when following the UMDF, but have no problem following the KMDF. So I changed the Debugger from "Debugging Tools for Windows - Remote Debugger" to "Debugging Tools for Windows - Kernel Debugger", and it works.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I am getting, "object reference not set to instance of object" when I switched to kernel debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but before the error i had a info that hardware id is not matching with .inf file all i did was entering <yourProjectName>.inf

and under

[Standard.NT$ARCH$]

%DeviceName% = ...

the name is after comma, you just have to swap it with the value that you entered in DriverInstall > Deployment > HardwareIdDriverUpdate

it was totally obvious for me but i couldn't find under what name i should look for hardware id value, so here it is :D