# winUSB Application DbgengRemoteCommand missing

Tags: c++, usb, winusb

I'm starting to program an access to a USB device, just like arduino. I'm using winUSB for this and I just finished the installation following every step. So I wanted to launch a USB application template but an error occured saying DbgengRemoteCommand is missing or empty. I don't really know what to do.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535278/driver-development-dbgengremotecommand-is-missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Driver Development DbgengRemoteCommand is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535278/driver-development-dbgengremotecommand-is-missing)